# parse ini file and put headers into CTreeViewCtrl and parameters into CListVewCtrl

Tags: winapi, ini

I need to write program whitch parse ini file and put headers into CTreeViewCtrl and parameters into CListViewCtrl.

For examp.

```
[header]
left = right
```

In program it will be like this

```
TREEVEIWCTRL splitter                List View
                |     leftside(column)        rightside(column)
  header        |          left                   right
```

Is there easier way to do it than read and parse every string of .ini file?

Answer (score 0):

You can either parse the ini file yourself, or use the various Private Profile APIs, such as [GetPrivateProfileSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724348%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and the like.  There may be a third party solution for ini files (or a LINQ solution if you're using C#).